# Position/meaning of deshalb in this sentence

Tags: subordinate-clause

I learned from my German course that *deshalb* is a connector and introduces a HS:

> Max möchte in Berlin studieren, deshalb lernt er Deutsch.

I came across the following phrase and can't figure out why *deshalb* is at this position:

> Wir haben einen kleinen Hund, von dem sich meine Kinder nicht trennen können und den wir deshalb auch mitnehmen müssten.

Comment: That phrase isn't an HS, it's a relative clause. Both the relative pronoun and the subject in a relative clause have to come as early as possible, and this supersedes the rule of thumb that 'deshalb' comes at the beginning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have probably fallen victim to didactic oversimplification.

> Max lernt Deutsch, **weil** er in Berlin studieren **möchte**.
>
> Max möchte in Berlin studieren, **deshalb** **lernt** er Deutsch.

Sometimes, pairs as the one above are used to put *weil* and *deshalb* in opposition. While the former introduces subordinate, verb-final clauses ("Nebensätze"), the latter occurs in independent main clauses ("Hauptsätze"); at least, that is what the examples suggest.

Hopefully, such expositions at least point out that, *deshalb* being an adverb, it can occur after the finite verb as well, just like any other adverb.

> Ich lerne **jetzt** auch noch Spanisch.
>
> **Jetzt** lerne ich auch noch Spanisch.

Therefore, the following is possible as well.

> Max möchte in Berlin studieren. Seit einigen Monaten lernt er **deshalb** Deutsch.

It is no different when the adverb *deshalb* occurs in subordinate clauses, as it does in the relative clause in your example.

> Hast du gehört, **dass** Max in Berlin studieren möchte und (dass er) deshalb Deutsch lernt?
>
> einen kleinen Hund, **von dem** sich meine Kinder nicht trennen können und **den** wir deshalb mitnehmen müssen

Since you asked about the meaning: *deshalb* connects the two relative clauses in such a way that the first gives the reason for the second. A paraphrase would be:

> einen kleinen Hund, den wir mitnehmen müssen, weil sich die Kinder nicht von ihm trennen können

Word such as *weil, obwohl, wenn* etc. are known as [*Subjunktoren*](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/systematische-grammatik/384); they invariably introduce subordinate clauses. When using terms such as *Konnektor*, it is important to realise that the term unites parts of speech that behave completely different, i.e. adverbs such as *deshalb, trotzdem, dann* (which are flexible in the manner shown above) and subjunctions such as *weil, obwohl, wenn*, which invariably introduce verb-final subordinate clauses. (Then there's also conjunctions such as *und, oder, denn*, which again behave in a different manner.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Took 30 minutes to understand what you said but it made sense in the end. I guess I got confused because deshalb is used in the relativ satz.